# Turn off history for Durandal child router

Tags: javascript, durandal, durandal-2.0

I'm using the child routers in `Durandal` for tab control.

However whenever you change tab, it creates a history event. Again and again. It has made my "Close" button pointless because I cannot `router.navigateBack()` anymore (would need to many times).

Is there a way to navigate back beyond the current parent route, or make the child router create no history?

```
var childRouter = m_router
    .createChildRouter()
    .makeRelative({ moduleId: 'viewmodels/manage/bill/center', fromParent: true })
    .map([
        { route: ['contract', ''], moduleId: 'contract', title: 'Contracts', nav: true },
        { route: 'job', moduleId: 'job', title: 'Jobs', nav: true },
        { route: 'order', moduleId: 'order', title: 'Orders', nav: true }
    ]).buildNavigationModel();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is just to not place an entry into history.  You can do this like so -

```
router.navigate('your/hash/here', { replace: true, trigger: false });
```

When your child router is making a route change.

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html#triggering-navigation

Comment: This is for triggering manual navigation. However if the user clicks on an `<a>` link with the hash which are making up the tabs, it will create the history.

Comment: Just map the anchor to a function instead.

Comment: I concede that would work, but I would like to avoid binding anchors to functions all the time.

Comment: You could watch the activeInstruction and wipe it out but that seems even worse than binding an anchor to a function :)